# Form get - remove the not selected

Tags: html, forms

I have a html form

```
    <form method="get" action="http://domainn.com/">
    <div class="item">
        <span>order_by</span>
        <select class="input" name="order_by">
            <option value="">DF</option>
            <option value="id">id</option>
            <option value="year">year</option>
        </select>
    </div><div class="item">
        <span>category</span>
        <select class="input" name="category">
            <option value="">DF</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Search">
    </div>
</form>
```

When clicking on it will move to buttu find links domain/?order_by=&category =

I want only values ​​are selected to appear on the link

For example, just select the category that it will not switch to select order_by domain/?category=1 not link domain/?order_by=&category=1

Comment: You can use a javascript function to remove the elements from the DOM that are not selected on submit using onsubmit="return functionname();" That should make the GET value disappear

Comment: you write the code to go . Thanksssssssssss